# Clicking on color swatch, images are not loading on product listing page in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, swatches, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

I have added color swatches for my Configurable products.
On product detail page when we click on color swatches the product images gets changed properly.
But this does not work fine on category pages.
When i click on color swatch, the images does not load.
https://prnt.sc/10gzh73

**And it is showing following error on console.**

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).AddFotoramaVideoEvents is not a function
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.updateBaseImage (swatch-renderer.js:1254)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.updateBaseImage (widget.js:100)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._ProductMediaCallback (swatch-renderer.js:1173)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._ProductMediaCallback (widget.js:100)
    at Object.mediaSuccessCallback [as success] (swatch-renderer.js:1074)
    at fire (jquery.js:3238)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3368)
    at done (jquery.js:9846)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:10317)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check `Magento_ProductVideo` enable or not? If not enabled then try enabling it. After this, if this issue is not solved then here is a temporary fix for this. You need to override the **swatch-renderer.js** file.

Path: **Magento_Swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js**
Override the above file at your theme path and make the below change in code.

> Replace this code

```
if (isInitial) {
   $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents();
}
```

> With this one

```
if (isInitial) {
    if ($.isFunction($(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents)) {
        $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but now got different error.   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.updateBaseImage (swatch-renderer.js:1263)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.updateBaseImage (widget.js:100)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._ProductMediaCallback (swatch-renderer.js:1173)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._ProductMediaCallback (widget.js:100)
    at Object.mediaSuccessCallback [as success] (swatch-renderer.js:1074)
    at fire (jquery.js:3238)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3368)
    at done (jquery.js:9846)

Comment: "if (gallery) {gallery.first();}" check this code in swatch-renderer.js file at 1263 line. Try to console "gallery" before "first()" and wrap with is not undefined confined. Like: "if (typeof(gallery.first()) != "undefined")"

Comment: By doing this thr is no error. But the image does not change when the color is selected. It loads first image only.